# Consider the proposition proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

**If x and y are even then x + y is even.**

```
Hypothesis : x and y is even 
Conclusion : x + y is even 
Proof: assume x = 2k 
              y = 2l 
then x + y = 2k + 2l 
           = 4kl 
           = 2(2kl) 
Therefore x + y is even.
```

Just wanted to see if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 0):

$x+y =2k+2l$

$x+y=2(k+l)$

No matter what $k$ and $l$ is, $2$ multiplied by any integer is even

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is even then there is an integer $a$ such that $x = 2a$. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are both even. It follows that there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $x = 2a$ and $y=2b$. Then $x + y = 2a + 2b = 2(a+b)$, so $a+b$ is evidently an integer for which $x+y = 2(a+b)$ and therefore $x+y$ is even.